# Correct type of wire for simple DIY projects involving soldering

Tags: connector, soldering, wiring, diy

I am making my own bluetooth speaker which will require me soldering wire to PCBs etc. However, I am unsure of which type of wire to buy for the project. I understand that positive and negative wiring is typically red and black, with speaker wires typically being black and white.

Am I requiring standard strand wiring that I will need to twist to strengthen before soldering, or should I be looking for solid core?

I have found [**this**](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Electrical-Wire-Red-Black-1-Metre-2-Pin-Wire-Copper-1-Meter-Extension-Cable/283352329998?hash=item41f91d6f0e:g:gwQAAOSw44BYiHDd) Ebay wiring that looks ok, but I am just wanting a bit of guidance.

For your information: The voltage expected through the circuit will be approx 5 - 6.5V with a current of between 1-2A

Comment: Stranded wire is often preferable for most everything but direct breadboard insertion  and wire wrap.  Silicone insulation makes it a lot easier to solder without excessive strip back or making a mess.  Beware that your overall project has a fairly high chance of not being practical; it's the kind of thing you should probably just buy, and save DIY for things that aren't available in more functional form off the shelf.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes I understand that after buying the components the other night, it would be cheaper to buy one and dismantle and incorporate into my own enclosure. But it is a learning experience for me :D

Comment: Stranded wire is often twisted at connections so loose stands don't stick out, but twisting will not improve the strength. Any wire soldered to a board should ideally have some form of stress relief so the joint does not support the wire. This could be in the form of cable ties or feeding the wire through a mounting hole first. Sometimes a knot can be added. Regarding the colours, they are not important to your simple DIY project - just use what you can get on a budget. I would use pvc insulated wire because it is cheap and soldering should be fine so long as you are quick.

Comment: @physicsboy I think that wire in the eBay link looks overpriced. Equipment wire 7/0.2 (7 strands of 0.2mm) would probably be fine. I'd expect to pay about £6.00 for 100m.

Comment: @Pzy I know it is slightly overpriced. But as all of the components I've bought for this... because I'm not buying them in the thousands and only plan on making 1 or 2 of these speakers... I'm paying for their low run numbers. But hey-ho. Whatever makes the girlfriend happy aye? XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this will do the job.

I used a wire similar to this for a project of mine and it worked perfectly.

Remember : Before soldering, strip a bigger part of the wire than you think you need to give your self extra room while soldering.